# CollectionView doesn't show images

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Helllo there!

I'm working on a project where you can put a pin on a map, tap the pin and see a collection view with Flickr images associated with the location.

Everything works fine instead of actually showing the images. I have a `print`-statement which shows, that there is an image if you tap it but it just shows the black background and I can't figure out what's wrong.

I connected the dataSource and delegate to the VC but it still doesn't work and doesn't even show up images I copied right into Xcode.

This is the code for the `GalleryViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import MapKit
import CoreData

class VTGalleryVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, Delegate, FinishedDownloadDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var newImageSetButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var pin: Pin!

var selectedImages = [NSIndexPath]()
var insertImages: [NSIndexPath]!
var deleteImages: [NSIndexPath]!
var updateImages: [NSIndexPath]!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if FlickrImageDelegate.sharedInstance().loading(pin.location!) {
        FlickrImageDelegate.sharedInstance().addDelegate(pin.location!, delegate: self)
    } else {
        self.fetch()
        if self.pin.location!.isLoading() {
            for next in pin.location!.myImages {
                if let downloader = ImageDownload.sharedInstance().downloading[next.description.hashValue] as? ImageLoader {
                    downloader.finishedDownloadDelegate.append(self)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if let details = self.pin.location!.details {
        self.navigationItem.title = details.locationName
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.mapView.removeAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations)
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.pin)
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Back"
    let coordinateRegion: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: self.pin.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1.0, longitudeDelta: 1.0))
    self.mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let collectionLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    collectionLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    collectionLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    collectionLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    let length = floor(self.collectionView.frame.size.width/3)
    collectionLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: length, height: length)

    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = collectionLayout
}

@IBAction func newImageSetButonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    for myImage in self.pin.location!.myImages {
        myImage.location = nil
        myImage.ownImage = nil
        self.sharedContext.deleteObject(myImage)
    }
    self.imagesForLocation()
    CDManager.sharedInstance().save()
}

func imagesForLocation() {
    FlickrImageDelegate.sharedInstance().searchImages(self.pin.location!)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    FlickrImageDelegate.sharedInstance().addDelegate(pin.location!, delegate: self)
}

func setupCell(cell: PhotoCVCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //cell.downloadedPhoto = self.fetchResultsC.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Image
    print(cell.downloadedPhoto)
}

lazy var fetchResultsC: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Image")
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "imagePath", ascending: true)]
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "location == %@", self.pin.location!)

    let fetchController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: self.sharedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "images")
    fetchController.delegate = self
    return fetchController
}()

lazy var sharedContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    return CDManager.sharedInstance().stack.managedObjectContext
}()

func fetch() {
    var error: NSError?
    NSFetchedResultsController.deleteCacheWithName("images")
    do {
        try self.fetchResultsC.performFetch()
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
    }
    if let _ = error {
        print(error)
    }
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return self.fetchResultsC.sections?.count ?? 0
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let info = self.fetchResultsC.sections![section]
    if let photos = self.pin!.location?.myImages where photos.count == 0 && self.isViewLoaded() && self.view.window != nil && self.newImageSetButton.enabled && !FlickrImageDelegate.sharedInstance().loading(pin.location!) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.imagesForLocation()
        }
    }
    return info.numberOfObjects
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let imageCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoCVCell
    //imageCell.imageCell.image = UIImage(named: "Cabin.png")
    self.setupCell(imageCell, indexPath: indexPath)
    return imageCell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let imageCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! PhotoCVCell
    if let index = selectedImages.indexOf(indexPath) {
        selectedImages.removeAtIndex(index)
    } else {
        selectedImages.append(indexPath)
    }
    self.setupCell(imageCell, indexPath: indexPath)
}

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    insertImages = [NSIndexPath]()
    deleteImages = [NSIndexPath]()
    updateImages = [NSIndexPath]()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        self.insertImages.append(newIndexPath!)
        break
    case .Delete:
        self.deleteImages.append(indexPath!)
        break
    case .Update:
        self.updateImages.append(indexPath!)
    default:
        break
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    if self.insertImages.count > 0 {
        self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(self.insertImages)
    }
    if self.deleteImages.count > 0 {
        self.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(self.deleteImages)
    }
    if self.updateImages.count > 0 {
        self.collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(self.updateImages)
    }
}

func searchedForLocationImages(success: Bool, location: Location, images: [Image]?, error: String?) {
    for next in pin.location!.myImages {
        if let downloader = ImageDownload.sharedInstance().downloading[next.description.hashValue] as? ImageLoader {
            downloader.finishedDownloadDelegate.append(self)
        }
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.fetch()
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

func finishedLoad() {}
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you check, whether your reuseIdentifier is fine? try for once setting the image to something you have on your disk. Just a random image by using in your cellForItemAtIndexPath : imageCell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "name.png")

Comment: it seems that your collectionViewController has trouble getting the reusable cell, check whether you set the reusable cell of class "PhotoCVCell" and set it's identifier correct, if they are all good, try to put the cell in a single xib file and let the collectionViewController register the cell in viewDidLoad